dynamic variable in Pentaho
Suppose, I have set multiple variables in pentaho with values like following picture:

I have set it in global variable like : $YYYYMMDD:DD-1, $YYYYMM00:DD-1,...
Now, I have a table named 'xyz' with var_item column having records like:

How do I set value of those variables to records of var_item column, then insert those values to new column  in 'xyz' table ?
The result I expecting like following pic:


please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

When you talk about "variable", do you mean "Parameters", from a transformation ? Can you please be more specific on the data you have and the result you want from it ? (You want to join a table ? From SQL ?)
